# How to force sum limits to be above and below the sigma in a Latex table

Tags: tables

Is there a way in the Latex tabular environment to force the limits on a sum to be above and below the Sigma?

I really need this table to be less wide without reducing the font size and if I could make this change I think it will reduce the width enough

```
\begin{tabular}{cccccc}
\toprule
%\multicolumn{2}{c}{iNaturalist data per species} \\
%\midrule
Year & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Number of\\ observers\end{tabular}  &\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Number of\\observer walks\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Expected number\\of individuals\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Actual number\\of individuals\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Number of\\observations\end{tabular} \\
\midrule
1  & $K_1$ & $W_1 = \sum_{k=1}^{K_1}Pois(E(W^{(k)}))$ & $E(n_1)$ & $n_1 = Pois(E(n_1))$ & $x_1 = \sum_{w=1}^{W_1} bin(n_1,p)$\\
\addlinespace[0.2cm]
2  & $K_2$ & $W_2 = \sum_{k=1}^{K_2}Pois(E(W^{(k)}))$ & $E(n_2) = E(n_1) e^t$ & $n_2 = Pois(E(n_2))$ & $x_2 = \sum_{w=1}^{W_2} bin(n_2,p)$\\
\addlinespace[0.2cm]
$\vdots$ &$\vdots$ &$\vdots$&$\vdots$ &$\vdots$ &$\vdots$\\
\addlinespace[0.2cm]
7 & $K_7$ & $W_7 = \sum_{k=1}^{K_7}Pois(E(W^{(k)}))$ & $E(n_7) =E(n_1) e^{6t}$& $n_7  =Pois(E(n_7))$& $x_7 = \sum_{w=1}^{W_7} bin(n_7,p)$ \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```

[image]

Comment: Use `\displaystyle` before each sum

Comment: @JairoAraujo -- `\displaystyle` may affect other things in the table cell.  `\sum\limits` is more reestrictive, acting on only the `\sum`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

For sums with limits below and above sum symbol you can use `\sum\limits_{...}^{...}`. I also change `tabular` to `array` and define two math operators:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Pois}{Pois}
\DeclareMathOperator{\bin}{bin}

\usepackage{booktabs, makecell}
\newcommand\mcc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{\text{\makecell{#1}}}}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{array}{@{} *{6}{c} @{}}
    \toprule
\mcc{Year}
    &   \mcc{Number of\\ observers}  
        &   \mcc{Number of\\observer walks} 
            &   \mcc{Expected number\\of individuals} 
                &   \mcc{Actual number\\of individuals} 
                    &   \mcc{Number of\\observations}   \\
    \midrule
1  & K_1 & W_1 = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{K_1}\Pois(E(W^{(k)}))
            & E(n_1)
                & n_1 = \Pois(E(n_1))
                    & x_1 = \sum\limits_{w=1}^{W_1} \bin(n_1,p) \\
    \addlinespace
2  & K_2 & W_2 = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{K_2}\Pois(E(W^{(k)}))
            & E(n_2) = E(n_1) e^t
                & n_2 = \Pois(E(n_2))
                    & x_2 = \sum\limits_{w=1}^{W_2} \bin(n_2,p)\\
    \addlinespace
\vdots &\vdots &\vdots&\vdots &\vdots &\vdots\\
    \addlinespace
7 & K_7 & W_7 = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{K_7}\Pois(E(W^{(k)}))
            & E(n_7) =E(n_1) e^{6t}& n_7=\Pois(E(n_7))
                & x_7 = \sum\limits_{w=1}^{W_7} \bin(n_7,p) \\
    \bottomrule
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

**Adendum**:
With use of the `\displaystyle` in table's column definition:

```
\begin{array}{@{} *{6}{>{\displaystyle}c} @{}}
```

you can drop all `\limits` in the table body code. With this the code for the table become a bit shorter.

Comment: Thank you - that is perfect!